# get java object array from scala list

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I'm working with apache reflection, and there is a java method whose signature is

```
public static Object invokeStaticMethod(Class cls, String methodName,
  Object[] args)
```

And my code is

```
object Tobject {
  def echo(name: String) =
    println("echo 1")

  def echo2(name: String, arg: String) =
    println ("echo 2")
}



class ApacheReflection extends FunSuite {

  test("apache reflection") {
    val factory = ClassUtils.getClass("Tobject")

    MethodUtils.invokeStaticMethod(factory,"echo2", List("sf", "f").asJava)

  }

}
```

And I got exception message

```
No such accessible method: echo2() on class: Tobject
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such accessible method: echo2() on class: Tobject
```

it seems that asJava can convert scala list to java list but not array, so how can I get java array from scala list?

Comment: AFAIK, scala use Array from java. So just convert list.toArray and this is enough.

Comment: I do know that. But list.toArray is not working. The thing is that invokeStaticMethod has two overload methods. the first one has object as argument and the second one has object[] as argument. No matter what argument I give to it, it just regard my argument as object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea to use .toArray is a good try. But it gives *Array[String]* (= *String[]* in Java), which is not the same as *Array[Object]* (= *Object[]*) for Java. On the other hand, if you use

```
List("sf", "f").toArray[Object]
```

everything works.